# How to logically tell than an UNO is being, or about to be programmed

Tags: serial, programming, midi

I have an MIDI application that uses the RX and TX serial interface.  When I program the UNO there is a collision between the on board programmer and the MIDI application RX serial port.  The MIDI shield provides a jumper to disconnect to prevent the collision during programming.

I would like to add a FET switch to open and close if I am programming, but it's not clear to me that there is a signal I can tap into on the UNO that indicates programming is about to start or that it has just finished.

I was thinking about using a pull up on a digital pin on the UNO that drives low when the program starts up. That might be the way to go, but I assumed that this must be a common issue with a common solution that I am just not finding on stack exchange.
Is there a standard logical way to tell that UNO is about to be programmed via the onboard USB port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposed solution is the normal method. A GPIO pin which is an "Activate Device" signal. It's pulled in one direction, the "inactive" direction, and you actively drive it in the other "active" direction in your program.